# Is it valid to include duration of follow-up as a covariate in a linear model?

Tags: linear-model, panel-data

I have longitudinal health data with:

- a quantitative outcome (duration of treatment with a drug Y)
- a binary exposure (receipt of drug Z).
- another binary covariate, q
- varying duration of follow-up

DAG here:

[image]

As the outcome is a duration and follow-up is uneven, it can be influenced by duration of follow-up (if someone stays in the study for a longer period, there's a higher chance that the duration of treatment would be longer). Duration of follow-up will also influence the main exposure.

Is it reasonable to fit a linear model that includes the duration of follow-up as a covariate?

```
duration_y ~ drug_z + q + duration_followup
```

Alternatively, could I standardise duration_y dividing it by the duration of followup, and then model the proportion instead with beta regression?

```
proportion_on_y ~ drug_z + q
```

Comment: @Ben - the longer the follow-up, the higher the probability of the participant being prescribed the medication. This is for many reasons - for example, the participant could develop with time one of many conditions that need treating with drug Z or drug Y. Or, more frequently - certain medications are given empirically, i.e., to see if they make the patient better, even if there isn't strong evidence that they have developed a specific condition. So it would be impossible to account for mediators or other confounders.